# Go and Callbacks

Tags: go

I believe the use of channels is preferred over callbacks, is there a way to rewrite this with channels that is more idiomatic or is the use of callbacks ok here:

```
type SomeServer struct { }

func RunSomeServer(callback func(SomeServer)) {
    someServer := SomeServer{}
    // do some other setup
    callback(someServer)
    // tear things down
}

func TestSomeServer(t *testing.T) {
    // some server only exists for the lifetime of the callback
    RunSomeServer(func(someServer SomeServer) {
        // run some tests against some Server
    })
}
```

Comment: Channels aren't preferred over callbacks, the standard library uses this style of callbacks all over the place, it highly depends on what you need to do. Also you probably should be passing `*SomeServer`.

Comment: Also look to the http class for another common pattern, where you pass a handler that conforms to an interface. In particular, consider how `HandlerFunc()` allows you to bridge easily from a callback function into a "handler object". All of this is orthogonal to channels.

Comment: Thanks OneOfOne and Rob. This did feel like the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

Using callbacks is very acceptable, specially for that kind of server pattern, `net/*` uses it all over the place.

However, the channel version could look something like:

```
func RunSomeServer() <- chan *SomeServer {
    ch := make(chan *SomeServer)
    someServer := &SomeServer{}
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            ch <- someServer //make sure someServer handles concurrent access
        }
        close(ch)
        //tear things down
    }()

    return ch
}

func TestSomeServer(t *testing.T) {
    ch := RunSomeServer()
    for ss := range ch {
        _ = ss
        //do stuff with ss
    }
}
```